# Transform data into nested JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, transformation

I am working with javascript for the first time, and I have an array of around 35000 objects, where each object looks like this:
`{city: 'city1', buildingtype: 'buildingtype1', day: 1, hour: 1, energy: 59}`

I want to sort this data into a **"nested" JSON object**, with cities as the first object. For each city, I then need to sort by buildingtype, and for each buildingtype I want an array with the energy, sorted by time.

I have added an image here which might explain it a bit better:
[image: Image of what I want to achieve]

I have begun with something like this

```
  let transformed_data = {}


  $:{
    datapoints.forEach((d)=> {
      if(!(d.city in transformed_data)){
        transformed_data[city] = {};
      }

      }
    )
  }
```

Would this be a good way to move forward?

Edit:
Thanks to some nice help this is the solution I found, where I used that the data was already sorted to my advantage.

```
  let transformed_data = {}


  $:{
    datapoints.forEach((d)=> {
      if(!(d.city in transformed_data)){
        transformed_data[d.city] = {};
      }
      if (!(d.buildingtype in transformed_data[d.city])){
        transformed_data[d.city][d.buildingtype] = [];
      }
      transformed_data[d.city][d.buildingtype].push(d.total_heating_energy)
      }
    )
  }
```

The resulting object can be found here: [Final_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtsyU.png)

Comment: `...sorted by time.` what does this mean? Do you have a timestamp or time has to be calculated based on `day` and `hour`?

Comment: Time has to be calculated based on day and hour. If it makes life easier, the array of objects is already sorted by first city, then buildingtype, then day, then hour.

Comment: If your input data is already sorted, then you should just need to add the values in the order they come. // You should check if `transformed_data[city]` already exists, if not, initialize it as an empty object. Then the same for `transformed_data[city][buildingtype]` - if it doesn't exist yet, initialize it as an empty array. And then you simply push the current energy value onto `transformed_data[city][buildingtype]`